# Trying to add a click event to individual elements but want them to execute one at a time

Tags: javascript, html

I have three div elements on a page and when each one is clicked they are supposed to disappear one at a time. Right now when I click one div element, they all disappear as a group. How do I make them disappear one at a time?

HTML

```
<div id=parentlist>
<div id="alert">
  <span class="closebtn">&times;</span> 
  <strong>Error!</strong>
</div>

<div id="alert2">
    <span class="closebtn">&times;</span> 
    <strong>Success!</strong>
  </div>



<div id="alert3">
   <span class="closebtn">&times;</span> 
    <strong>Warning!</strong>
  </div>

  </div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
document.addEventListener("click", function(){

    document.getElementById('alert').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('alert2').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('alert3').style.display = 'none';




});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create an `Array` and then add an event listener to every element in the array using `Array.forEach` method of ES6.

The Code:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var divs = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.alerts'));
  divs.forEach(div => div.addEventListener('click', function() {
    div.style.display = 'none';
  }));
}
```

```html
<div id=parentlist>
  <div id="alert" class='alerts'>
    <span class="closebtn">&times;</span> 
    <strong>Error!</strong>
  </div>

  <div id="alert2" class='alerts'>
    <span class="closebtn">&times;</span> 
    <strong>Success!</strong>
  </div>
  
  <div id="alert3" class='alerts'>
    <span class="closebtn">&times;</span> 
    <strong>Warning!</strong>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you @Rahul this is exactly what I was looking for. I see the alerts was changed to one single class and they were all consolidated using the for each method. I will look more into the Array.from() since this is a new concept for me. TWO thumbs up for this response!

Answer (score 1):

You can try using timeout like this

```js
document.addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.getElementById('alert').style.display = 'none';
  setTimeout(() => {
    document.getElementById('alert2').style.display = 'none';
    setTimeout(() => {
      document.getElementById('alert3').style.display = 'none';
    }, 500);
  }, 500);
});
```

```html
<div id=parentlist>
  <div id="alert">
    <span class="closebtn">&times;</span>
    <strong>Error!</strong>
  </div>

  <div id="alert2">
    <span class="closebtn">&times;</span>
    <strong>Success!</strong>
  </div>
  <div id="alert3">
    <span class="closebtn">&times;</span>
    <strong>Warning!</strong>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you @ZohirSalak CeNa I actually want them to disappear one at a time upon clicking them but this is a good learning point.

Comment: Oh well, you didn't make that clear, i just worked from your code and assumed the behavior, but not matter :)